# how to reset password using email in laravel 5

Tags: email, laravel, reset

i want to reset password using email which is defalt provided by laravel 5.
i don't have any idea or knowledge how is password reset code sent to email and use that password to do reset in laravel.

I have mail configuration correct now i want to send the user the password from email.

How to send email having password to gmail and how to put password and update password in our laravel project.

Comment: Have you tried looking at the documentation? http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/authentication#resetting-passwords

Answer (score 0):

For us to really help you, it is much better if you give something a try and if it doesn't work then post the code so that we can help you debug and improve it.

To begin with, I would suggest [reading the documentation](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/authentication#resetting-passwords) on how this all works.

Next, [this blog post](https://laraveltips.wordpress.com/2015/06/16/setting-up-a-forgot-password-form-and-controller-in-laravel-5-1/) lays the whole process out from start to finish on how to implement password reset functionality using the default files that come with Laravel. There is too much to post the whole process here so I suggest you attempt to follow it then when/if you run in to trouble then you have something that you can actually post for us to help you on.

Finally, [this package](https://github.com/bestmomo/scafold) provides the auth scaffold that was removed in Laravel 5 that you might find useful as it provides all the views etc for registering, logging in and resetting passwords.

Check those out, give it a go and then come back to us with specific issues that you are having and post the code that is causing the issues and we can help you much more from there.

**EDIT to clarify on comments**

*Trait*

> A Trait is intended to reduce some limitations of single inheritance
>   by enabling a developer to reuse sets of methods freely in several
>   independent classes living in different class hierarchies. The
>   semantics of the combination of Traits and classes is defined in a way
>   which reduces complexity, and avoids the typical problems associated
>   with multiple inheritance and Mixins.
>
> A Trait is similar to a class, but only intended to group
>   functionality in a fine-grained and consistent way. It is not possible
>   to instantiate a Trait on its own. It is an addition to traditional
>   inheritance and enables horizontal composition of behavior; that is,
>   the application of class members without requiring inheritance.

This is from the [PHP docs](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.traits.php), essentially it groups a whole load of functionality for us to use.

In this case the `ResetsPasswords` holds all of the actual code that resets the password and is called in to the Controller that handles this using `use ResetsPasswords;`.

Comment: trait ResetsPasswords
i don't understand this, do we have to create trait?
if we have to create where we have to create

Comment: can you explain the process how passowrd reset is done in laravel 5? i am not getting the idea

Comment: is this similiar for laravel 5?

Comment: Have you looked at and followed the blog post I suggested - https://laraveltips.wordpress.com/2015/06/16/setting-up-a-forgot-password-form-and-controller-in-laravel-5-1/?

Comment: You don't have to create the trait or anything - this is the stuff that already comes with Laravel.

Comment: I have posted an edit that should clarify this for you.

Comment: thank you lot... 
email password reset was working before and email was sent in spam folder. thank you james

Comment: @sabinmaharjan Awesome mate, if this answer helped then you should consider marking it as the accepted answer to give closure to the question :).